# Rspec for the following method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2

Can anyone please help me in writing rspec for the following method The write_entry_to_xml method write xml nodes.
The entry is an object which looks like

```
entry = Sitemap::Entry.new("http://www.example.com", 'monthly', 0.8, "2011-11-23 13:56:42 UTC")
```

---

```
def write_entry_to_xml(entry)
  node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new("url", @xml_document)
  node["loc"] = entry.loc
  node["lastmod"] = entry.lastmod.to_s
  node["changefreq"] =  entry.changefreq.to_s
  node["priority"] = entry.priority.to_s
  node.to_xml
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Write a spec that takes uses your methods with some sample input and check that the output is as expected. What don;t you understand?

Comment: @Frederick Cheung Can you please show me an example how can i create some pre defined input data for my methods and run my method with that data to confirms that the output is as what I expect...Thanks

Comment: Get this book: [The RSpec book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book), you'll have no questions :-)

Comment: I studied this book a bit but its urgent and I have to submit my semester project it today :( I dont know how to start at least give me a start with some code ... Thanks

Comment: :D submitting projects the last day is so much fun.

Comment: Not fun for me :( Guys please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you should know what the expected output of your method should be. We can't tell you what your code is supposed to be doing. Once you have that, your spec doesn't have to be anything more than

```
describe SomeClass do

  describe('write_entry_to_xml') do
    let(:entry) { Sitemap::Entry.new("http://www.example.com", 'monthly', 0.8, "2011-11-23 13:56:42 UTC")}

    it 'should return a properly formatted xml fragment' do
      SomeClass.write_entry_to_xml(entry).should == "<url>...</url>"
    end
  end
end
```

Here I've assumed that this method is a class method on `SomeClass` - change to match what you've done, you should also obviously replace "..." with the desired output

Comment: Can I have should matcher for multiple parts of the url , like for loc, frequence,  etc ... ?

Comment: That's up to you. You can check the entirety of the output in one go, or pull apart the string (e.g. specify that it contains a certain string fragment, matches a regular expression etc.) You could even parse it with nokogiri and verify that the parsed output contains what you want

Comment: How can I use nokogiri inside my spec I use it inmy method to format xml but how in spec?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to get some pre-defined data that you would use as input in ur spec.
1.

```
before :each do
    @input = input
   end
```

Now @input will be accessible to the specs as this block will be run before every spec.
2. You could define the inputs inside the spec as a local variable and then access it. If you require to access the same variable at many places then you can use the above method.

You could get some XML via using a library like [Builder](http://builder.rubyforge.org/).

```
 builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new

  xml = builder.url do | b|
    b.loc = "http://www.experteer.de/jobboerse/deutschland/jobs/mannheim"
    b.changefreq =0.8 
    b.priority = "monthly"
    b.lastmod = "2011-11-23 13:56:42 UTC"
  end
```

this code should give you the XML object. Do let me know if you need further help.

Comment: if my input is an array of data as I mentioned above how can I define it to be used in my spec

Comment: looks like you need some XMl data. You could have some string and parse it into XML using some ruby libraries and use it.

Comment: but how? give me a start please:(

Comment: In fill method first we open a file and then we write data into it. it would be great if you help me by writing in the proper spec structure because I have very little knowledge about rspec ... Thanks